# Объединить две таблицы и вывести результат

Tags: php, mysql

Есть две таблицы в mysql:

```
tovari (id, title)
otzivi (id, product_id, text)
```

Нужно объединить таблицы и вывести в итоге: отзыв (text), название товара (title). Как связать отзыв с товаром? Сейчас вывод отзывы такой:

```
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM otzivi ORDER BY id desc limit 8");
while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
echo '<p>'.$row["text"].'</p><p>Название товара</p>
';
}
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Answer (score 0):

Забираем данные из двух таблиц при помощи `JOIN`

```
<?php
$results = $mysqli->query("
    SELECT * 
    FROM feedbacks JOIN products ON products.id = product_id
    ORDER BY feedbacks.id desc limit 8
");

while($row = $results->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<p>'.$row["feedback"].'</p><p>'.$row["name"].'</p>';
}
```

[PHP MySQL online test](https://phpize.online/sql/mysql57/66e6beb5917b208c6716f26a34b4f610/php/php8/67c72a885eef331c092ca07a944fadfd/)